# I have a question which is a near fit for MathOverflow. What are some other resources I might consult?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, asking-questions

What are some other resources which might be useful for somebody considering asking a MathOverflow question, especially if their question is not quite a perfect fit here?

In asking this, I have several categories of resources in mind, including but not limited to:

1. Both online and offline resources; both resources on the [Stack Exchange Network](https://stackexchange.com/) and from elsewhere. (E.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics), [Zentralblatt](https://zbmath.org/).)
2. Resources for answering questions about mathematics which fall outside of MathOverflow's scope because they are not ["research-level"](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2658/research-level-mathematics). (E.g. [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).)
3. Resources for answering questions related to mathematics which are best answered by different communities with non-mathematical expertise. (E.g. [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) or [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).)
4. Other mathematical communities whose expertise may be complementary to that of the community here. (E.g. various discipline-specific mailing lists and discussion boards, or databases such as [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).)
5. Resources for answering questions about MathOverflow or about the Stack Exchange network (e.g. [MathOverflow meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/) or [meta stack exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)).

As I've stated it, it sounds like I'm asking for an unimaginably comprehensive list of resources for questions related to mathematics — obviously it would be nigh-impossible to actually compile an authoritative answer to the question as I've framed it. But there's a loophole, in that so far as possible I'd like to address each of these categories of mathematical resources via a meta-category of resources, namely:

0. Meta-resources: Lists compiled elsewhere on the internet which themselves compile lists of resources of the above types. (E.g. [Collecting math websites](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4032983/collecting-math-websites) is an example of a list of mathematics websites compiled on Mathematics Stack Exchange. [Useful mathematical fora](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95787/useful-mathematical-fora) is another, focused on mathematics forums.)

Comment: Have you tried making sacrifices to long-forgotten gods? Statistically speaking, there's a better chance one of those is in charge of whatever thing you're trying to solve.

Comment: I sacrificed a bull to Athena and an ibis to Thoth, but when they heard it wasn't on MathOverflow they were out of ideas

Comment: I said *long-forgotten*, clearly not Athena and Thoth. I was thinking more pre-Columbian deities of the Americas.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the sort of lead I was hoping for!

Comment: I was thinking what tags might be suitable here. I thought that maybe ([meta-tag:closed-questions]) and perhaps also ([meta-tag:asking-questions]). If it is intended as a FAQ post, ([meta-tag:faq-proposed]) could be added.

Comment: Some resources for your second point (not research-level) are listed here: [My question was closed on MO because it is not research level. Where should I ask instead?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3760) This post is linked also from [Frequently Asked Questions: MathOverflow FAQ](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/203#207) ([current revision](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/revisions/207/8)) and in the [help center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic).

Comment: When you mentioned *discipline-specific mailing lists*, you reminded me of this post: [Mailing lists / Usenet groups for research math](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3214). (It is from 2017, quite a few things might have changed since then.)

Comment: Maybe I am posting too many links, but still I'll add two posts from [math.meta.se]: [What are some alternatives to math.stackexchange where discussions are allowed?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34331) and [What is a good forum for math discussion?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25878)

Comment: @MartinSleziak These links are fantastic, thanks! I guess the way I framed the question it might seem a bit daunting to try formatting them into the form of a (partial) answer. If you'd prefer not to write a (partial) answer yourself, I can try to compile some of these into a (partial) answer. Also, your suggestion that this might end up being something we could tag [meta-tag:faq-proposed] seems interesting. If it goes well enough, that may be exactly what we should do!

Comment: As [mentioned in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2022/5/14), I wasn't sure whether these questions would fit some of the categories listed in the question: [Most helpful math resources on the web](https://mathoverflow.net/q/2147) and [Atlas-like websites on specific areas of mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/q/354327). Perhaps they could fall under "0. Meta-resources"?

Answer (score 5):

4. More discussion-based fora.

Here are a few of other places (from [Math Stack Exchange Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/)) to find places to talk about math online in a more discussion-based format:

- [What are some alternatives to math.stackexchange where discussions are allowed?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34331)
- [What is a good forum for math discussion?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25878)
- [Collecting math websites](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4032983/collecting-math-websites)
- [Useful mathematical fora](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95787/useful-mathematical-fora)
- Discipline-specific mailing lists: a few are compiled [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3214/mailing-lists-usenet-groups-for-research-math).
- There are various mathematical communities on platforms such as [zulip](https://zulip.com/), [discord](https://discord.com/), [slack](https://slack.com/), etc. Most of these require some sort of invitation to join. For instance, there is an [Algebraic Topology Discord Server](https://discord.gg/qUUbQDf4Cw), which has roots in the [homotopy theory chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9417/homotopy-theory).

Other mathematical communities include https://math.codidact.com/ and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/):

https://old.reddit.com/r/abstractalgebra/
https://old.reddit.com/r/AppliedMath/
https://old.reddit.com/r/askmath/
https://old.reddit.com/r/combinatorics/
https://old.reddit.com/r/DifferentialEquations/
https://old.reddit.com/r/mathematics/
https://old.reddit.com/r/math/
https://old.reddit.com/r/maths/
https://old.reddit.com/r/MathHelp/
https://old.reddit.com/r/mathshelp/
https://old.reddit.com/r/Probability/
https://old.reddit.com/r/probabilitytheory/
https://old.reddit.com/r/puremathematics/
https://old.reddit.com/r/topology/

#### Statistics

https://old.reddit.com/r/AskStatistics/
https://old.reddit.com/r/datascience/
https://old.reddit.com/r/econometrics
https://old.reddit.com/r/MathStats/
https://old.reddit.com/r/StatisticsZone/
https://old.reddit.com/r/TheoreticalStatistics/

Comment: I was really expecting to find a list of mathematical databases and a list of mathematical mailing lists on the AMS website, but I could not find either. I do hope that some of the mathematical communities on collaboration platforms mentioned above might become more openly discoverable somehow.

Answer (score 2):

#### Various math-related databases

For example, databases of various mathematical objects.

The website [Catalogue of Mathematical Datasets](https://mathdb.mathhub.info/) has a very impressive collection of various databases.

At least some databases are listed here:

- [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) - [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-Line_Encyclopedia_of_Integer_Sequences)
- π-Base - a database located here: https://topology.pi-base.org/ and https://topology.jdabbs.com/. It could be described as (expanded) online version of [Counterexamples in Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology).
- Database of Ring Theory - https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/ (Here in the Stack Exchange network you can find also a [related chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/91076/dart).)

Some related posts here on MathOverflow and on Mathematics Stack Exchange:

- [What could be some potentially useful mathematical databases?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/68442)
- [Atlas-like websites on specific areas of mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/q/354327)
- [Is there a database for tracking the dependencies of mathematical theorems?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/249383)
- [Wiki for consequences of axiom of choice?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/373775)
- [Category Theory Zoo](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1639034) and [A comprehensive list of categories](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3928971)

Answer (score 1):

2. If your question is about mathematics, but not research-level mathematics, then you can find some great alternative resources at the following MathOverflow Meta question:

   - [My question was closed on MO because it is not research level. Where should I ask instead?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3760).

Answer (score 1):

5. Meta questions.

- If your question is about MathOverflow itself, then right here on [MathOverflow Meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/) is the place to ask.
- If your question is about the Stack Exchange Network, you might try [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), or look at the [Stack Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/).

Answer (score 1):

3. Not purely mathematical questions:

- You might check one of the numerous [science sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#science-traffic) or [technology sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-traffic) here on the Stack Exchange network.
- In another direction, [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) or [Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Reference tools.

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)
- [PlanetMath](https://planetmath.org/)
- [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Main_Page)
- [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage)
- [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/)
- [Zentralblatt](https://zbmath.org/)
- [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page) - a wiki which contains various mathematical results and their proofs. (At least in some cases the article contains references, too.)
- Several wikis [hosted on subwiki](https://subwiki.org/) - such as [Groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page), [Topospaces](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page) and a few others.

Comment: The links ought to be annotated. For example, what is the gist of each of those sites (in this context)? What is their use (in this context)? What do they contain (notable in this context)? What are some limitations, gotchas, or caveats?